# separating C++ code in to multiple files

Tags: c++

I hope you are all doing well.

I have the below code which manages a printing queue. I need to separate it into the below files and I dont know how to this. Oddly i've never been asked to do this. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated. I am not sure what code goes in which file.

Files I need to separate my code into:
1. heap.h - declaration file for heap.
2. heap.cpp - implementation file for heap.
3. pqtype.h - declaration file for priority queue.
4. pqtype.cpp - implementation file for priority queue.
5. test.cpp - driver file.

My current Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    int priority;
    int jNum;
    string jName;
    struct node *next;
};

class PriorityQueue
{
private:
    node *front;
public:

    PriorityQueue()
    {
        front = NULL;
    }

    void addJob(string item, int priority, int number)

    {
        node *temp, *q;
        temp = new node;
        temp->jName = item;
        temp->priority = priority;
        temp->jNum = number;
        //whether queue is empty

        if (front == NULL || priority < front->priority)
        {
            temp->next = front;
            front = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            q = front;
            while (q->next != NULL && q->next->priority <= priority)
                q = q->next;
            temp->next = q->next;
            q->next = temp;
        }
    }

    void printJob()

    {
        node *temp;
        if (front == NULL)
            cout << "There Are No Print Requests In The Queue.\n";
        else
        {
            temp = front;
            cout << "\nNow printing Request # " << temp->jNum << " " <<"For "<< temp->jName <<"\n"<< endl;
            front = front->next;
            free(temp);
        }
    }

    void viewJob()
    {
        node *ptr;
        ptr = front;
        if (front == NULL)
            cout << "There Are No Print Requests In The Queue\n\n";
        else
        {
            while (ptr != NULL)
            {
                cout << "Job #: " << ptr->jNum << " " <<"For "<< ptr->jName <<"\n"<< endl;
                ptr = ptr->next;
            }
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    int choice, priority;
    PriorityQueue pq;
    char ch;
    string jName;
    int number = 0;
    cout << "Printing Queue\n" << endl;

    do
    {
        cout << "==============" << endl;
        cout << "1. Add Job\n";
        cout << "2. Print Job\n";
        cout << "3. View Job\n";
        cout << "4. Exit\n";
        cout << "\nEnter Your Option Now : ";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Are You A Student (s or S), TA (t or T), Or Instructor (i or I)? ";
            cin >> ch;
            if (ch == 'i' || ch == 'I')
            {
                priority = 1;
                jName = "Instructor";
                cout << "\nJob Successfully Entered.\n\n";
            }
            else if (ch == 't' || ch == 'T')
            {
                priority = 2;
                jName = "TA";
                cout << "\nJob Successfully Entered.\n\n";
            }
            else if (ch == 's' || ch == 'S')
            {
                priority = 3;
                jName = "Student";
                cout << "\nJob Successfully Entered.\n\n";
            }
            number++;
            pq.addJob(jName, priority, number);
            break;

        case 2:
            pq.printJob();
            break;
        case 3:
            pq.viewJob();
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "\nThank You For Using Printint Queue\nProgram Now Closing...\n\n";
            break;
        default:
            cout << "\nInvalid Choice Selected! \n";
        }
    }
    while (choice != 4);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This as a thumb rule: Type definitons -> .h, function protoypes -> .h, extern variable declarations -> .h, global (extern/static) variable init. -> .cpp, function/method implementation -> .cpp, but inline methods/functions -> .h.

Comment: First extract the existing code into the Files. Don't change any logic. After that you can change the logic and clear the ugly code.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. It seems like your code-sample is different from the files you say you need (mainly "heap.h" and "heap.cpp" appears to not have any corresponding implementation in your code).